Archive List Items Annually
I have a list that I need to archive items from on the first of the year. My company is running on SharePoint 2019, but still uses SharePoint Designer 2013 and 2010 workflows. I am not a developer, but have some experience tinkering with java and html. I want to write a script or workflow that will trigger all list items with a certain value to move to a different list on the first day of each year. Is this possible?

I am afraid, you can't do this with Sharepoint Designer, just only with PowerShell scripts. Here is a good explanation: How can I run a workflow for all objects in a list at the same time?
